# Jest Calling async function

Tags: redux, jestjs

I have a function in redux store.

```
Func1(){

Dispatch(some action)
Dispatch(some action1)
result = Dispatch(some async action)\\promise retured

result.then(()=>
Dispatch(some other action)
)

}
```

My test case

```
Test(()=>{

Expectedactions= all 3 actions.
Axios.post.mockimplimetation(()=>
Promise.resolve(data))

calling Func1() from wrapper.

Expect(store.getActions()).toequal(expectedactions)

})
```

Test result shows only 2 actions.
Async action is not captured.

Please help me how to test this behaviour or what approach I shoud take.

Edited.

TestConrainer.js

```
const mapstatetoprops= (state)=>{
return {}
}
const mergeprops =(stateprops,dispatchprops,ownprops)=>{
const {dispatch}= dispatchprops

const f1=()=>{
dispatch(configActions.pause("Pause"))

let result = dispatch(DataActions.save(stateProps.data)

dispatch(configActions.setClick(false));

result.then((result) => {

dispatch(configActions.show(false));

dispatch(DataActions.StatusValue(""))
})

return Object.assign({},stateprops,ownprops,{
f1:f1
})
}
export default connect(mapstatetoprops,null,mergeprops)(Test)
```

DataActions.js

```
export const save = (data) => {

return (dispatch,getState) =>{ 
return axios.post(url, payload))

.then(data => {

return data;

},error => {
return error
}).catch(err){
return err
}
```

My test case

```
Test(()=>{

Expectedactions= all 3 actions.
Axios.post.mockimplimetation(()=>
Promise.resolve(data))

calling f1() from wrapper like
Wrapper.shallow(<TestContainer store=store/>)
Wrapper.find('Test').props().f1()

Expect(store.getActions()).toequal(expectedactions)

})
```

Test result shows only 2 actions.
Async action is not captured.

Please help me how to test this behaviour or what approach I shoud take.

Comment: `Dispatch(some other action)` etc will result in syntax error. Please, provide working code, not pseudocode. Promises should be chained and in your case they likely aren't. and it's unclear where exactly.

Comment: Added some working code. It may help you